# fatfree user auth global variable

Tags: php, authentication, fat-free-framework

Iam auth my user with the build in function. But is fatfree not setting the username global? Cant find it

```
    $angemeldet = new \DB\SQL\Mapper($this->db, 'users');
    $auth = new \Auth($angemeldet, array('id'=>'name', 'pw'=>'email'));
    $auth->basic(); // a network login prompt will display to authenticate the user
```

This is working.

http://www.willis-owen.co.uk/2013/02/blog-tutorial-with-fat-free-framework-v3/
Here i found that he is setting it in the SESSION. But if i try to access it, its completly empty. Where can i find the username?

And how can i manipulate the password? So i can compare a hash?

Answer (score 2):

The F3 Auth will not set the user to the `SESSION` by default, you would have to do that yourself. You can't store PDO objects in the `SESSION` because they can't be serialized. The username will be stored in the `SERVER.PHP_AUTH_USER`, so you can use that to fetch the `$user`.

To hash the password, you pass a function to the `$auth->basic( function( $password ){} );` and return the hashed password. Using `SHA256` with a salt will be much more secure than `MD5`.

This is the code I am using to do BASIC auth.

```
// I call this from the constructor of the handler of secure pages.
public static function authenticate(){
    // map to the users db table
    $user = new \DB\SQL\Mapper( F3::get( 'db' ), 'users' );
    // tell F3 to use the columns username and password
    $auth = new \Auth( $user, array( 'id'=>'username', 'pw'=>'password' ) );
    // check to see if they are authed, use a function to create hashed password
    $authenticated = $auth->basic( function ( $password ){
        $salt = 'Some secure salt string...';
        return hash( 'sha256', $password . $salt );
    } );
    // if we are logged in and the user isn't set....
    if ( $authenticated && !F3::exists( 'user' ) ){
        // use SERVER.PHP_AUTH_USER to load user by username 
        $user->load( array( 'username=?', F3::get( 'SERVER.PHP_AUTH_USER' ) ) );
        // set user to variable if it could be loaded
        if ( !$user->dry() ){
            F3::set( 'user', $user );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code below:

```
public function verify($f3, $params) {
    $username = $f3->get('POST.email');
    $password = $f3->get('POST.password');
    $hashedPassword = md5($password);
    $submit = $f3->get('POST.submit');

    if (isset($submit)) {
        global $db;
        $user = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db, 'users');

        // username is email, password is password in our case
        $auth = new \Auth($user, array('id' => 'email', 'pw' => 'password'));
        $loginResult = $auth->login($username, $hashedPassword); // Cross-check with users with hashedPassword

        // Authenticated the user successfully
        if ($loginResult == true) {
            $f3->set('message', 'Logged in successfully.');
            $f3->reroute('/login');
        }
    } else {
        $f3->set('message', 'Please enter valid username/password');

    }
   $f3->reroute('/login');

}
```

In the above code you can see that I have used md5 hash in the password. This might give you idea on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

check the API docs for the basic auth method: http://fatfreeframework.com/auth#basic

i think it should be something like

```
$auth->basic(function($input){
  return md5($input);
});
```

unfortunately this method does not return any user data on a valid login. but since objects are passed by reference in php, you could try to have a look at the mapper **after** the auth process, if some data was populated. `var_dump($angemeldet->cast());`

Comment: Too bad that the var dump variables are all NULL :(.

Comment: well then you would need to do a second call to the mapper to load the user data once more. :-/

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to do basic (browser popup) auth, from my experience:

```
function renderAdmin() {
    $user=new DB\SQL\Mapper($this->db,'users');
    $auth== null;
    $auth = new \Auth($user, array('id'=>'username', 'pw'=>'password'));
    $login_result = $auth->basic();
    if ($login_result) $f3->set('SESSION.username','SERVER.PHP_AUTH_USER');
    if (!$f3->get('SESSION.username')) $f3->error(401);
    else {          
        // all your code for the admin section
        echo \Template::instance()->render('admin.html'); 
    }
}
```